# show that $uv\in W^{1,r}(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded,with $\partial\Omega\in C^{1},p,q\geq 1$,$u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega),v\in W^{1,q}(\Omega)$,show that $ uv\in W^{1,r}(\Omega)$.here $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{n}$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{n}>0$,and $r=\min\{p,q\}$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{n}<0$ .

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  You can start with the simpler case: $u, v$ are also in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$.

Comment: I don't know how to deal with it,can you tell more detail? thank you very much! @mathematician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can prove (by approximating $u$ and $v$ by smooth functions) that
$$
D(uv) = u Dv + vDu.
$$
Assume first $p<n$ and $q<n$.
Then using Sobolev embedding theorem, we know that
$$
u\in L^{\frac{pn}{n-p}}(\Omega), \quad v\in L^{\frac{qn}{n-q}}(\Omega).
$$
Using Hoelder inequality one can prove that $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, $g\in L^q(\Omega)$ implies $fg\in L^r(\Omega)$ for all $r$ such that
$1/r \ge 1/p+1/q$ provided that $\Omega$ is has finite measure:
$$
\|fg\|_{L^r(\Omega)} = \int_\Omega |f|^r|g|^r 
\le \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^r \left(\int_\Omega |g|^{\frac{pr}{p-r}}\right)^{\frac{p-r}p}
\le \|f\|_{L^q(\Omega)}^r \|g\|_{L^q(\Omega)}^r |\Omega|^{r(\frac1r-\frac1p-\frac1q)}
$$

$$
%q'=q\frac{p-r}{pr}, 1/q'=\frac{pr}{qp-qr}, 1-1/q' = \frac{qp-qr-pr}{qp-qr},
%(1-1/q')(p-r)/p=\frac{qp-qr-pr}{qp}=r(1/r-1/p-1/q)
%$$
This implies
$$
uDv \in L^{r}(\Omega), \ vDu \in L^r(\Omega)
$$
if 
$$
\frac1r \ge \max( \frac{n-p}{pn}+\frac1q , \frac{n-q}{qn}+\frac1p) = \frac1p+\frac1q-\frac1n.
$$
Moreover, $uv\in L^r(\Omega)$ if
$$
\frac1r\ge \frac{n-p}{pn}+\frac{n-q}{qn} = \frac1p+\frac1q-\frac2n
$$
This completes the discussion if $p< n$ and $q<n$.

If $p>n$ and $q>n$ then $uv\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $D(uv)\in L^{\min(p,q)}(\Omega)$.
If $p<n$ and $q>n$ then $uv\in L^p(\Omega)$ and $D(uv)\in L^r(\Omega)$ if
$$
\frac1r\ge \max(\frac1p-\frac1n+\frac1q , \frac1p) = \frac1p = \frac1{\min(p,q)}.
$$
Similarly, the argument works for $p>n$ and $q<n$.

The claim is *false* if $p=n$ or $q=n$ holds. Then $uv\in W^{1,r}(\Omega)$ for all $r<\min(p,q)$.